# SQL query using if else statements for setting new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data in below format:

```
contractid         Contract-data
---------------------------------
 1                 {}
 1                 {result:A}
 1                 Null
 1                 Null
 2                 Null
 2                 Null
 2                 Null
 3                 Null
 3                 {}
 3                 {}
```

I need to get a query to return me something like this. Assume one can only have result:A only.

```
Contractid  Flag
-------------------
 1          A       // Since one of the rows of contract data contains result:A
 2          0       // since all rows of contract data contains null
 3          -1      //Since there is no result and only empty {}
```

Can someone help with the pointer for SQL option to use in SQL Server?

Comment: Show sample data as (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts), and desired output which matches this sample data precisely.

Comment: 1) *3 -1 //Since there is no result and only empty {}* I see a row `3 Null` in data source. 2) What is `{}` in `Contract-data`? Empty JSON array? 3) What if some contract has JSON object with 2 different values? 2 equal values? 2 different JSON with equal/different values? Show **ALL possible combinations** in data sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your sample data the following will work:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [contractid] INT
   ,[Contract-data] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([contractid], [Contract-data])
VALUES (1, '{}')
      ,(1, '{result:A}')
      ,(1, Null)
      ,(1, Null)
      ,(2, Null)
      ,(2, Null)
      ,(2, Null)
      ,(3, Null)
      ,(3, '{}')
      ,(3, '{}');

SELECT [contractid]
      ,MAX
       (
            CASE 
                WHEN [Contract-data] IS NULL THEN '0'
                WHEN [Contract-data] = '{}' THEN '-1'
                WHEN [Contract-data] IS NOT NULL AND [Contract-data] <> '{}' THEN REPLACE(REPLACE([Contract-data], '{result:', ''), '}', '')
            END
       )
FROM @DataSource
GROUP BY [contractid];
```

but you may need to extended the logic in the `CASE WHEN` statement because there might be various situations.

Let me know with a comment if the code is not working for particular scenario and you are not able to handle it by yourself.